# find -exec sed to find / replace with reusable string

Tags: sed, find

I am trying to build a small sh script that does a basic find / replace but with a small twist, that I wonder if I am going about it the wrong way.

here is the **old string**

`mysql_fetch_array($foo)`

here is what **i need**

`$foo->fetch_array()`

now the easy part is:

```
find . -type f -name "*.php" -exec sed -i'' -e 's/mysql_fetch_array(/->fetch_array(/g' {} +
```

But I don't know how to pull `$foo` from the parantheses, and then shove it up in front ...  Do I do this in the same `sed` regex ..  Do I store it in a variable and reconstruct it?  What's the most efficient way to go about this?

I have tried multiple things, but I am having trouble with escaping the `$` etc etc ...  My mind is thoroughly exhausted!

**EDIT**

It should be noted that I was needing to **match** `mysql_fetch_array` specifically as well -- my bad for not specifying it in the OP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find . -type f -name "*.php" -exec sed -i -e 's/^.*mysql_fetch_array(\$\([^)]*\))/$\1->fetch_array()/' {} \;
```

Comment: Ahh!  I see!  Use regex first to isolate and then reconstruct it ... clever!

Comment: Yeah. Matching the regex meta characters - '$' and '()' here - is so often a pain. If the replacement is simple enough, just ignoring them in the match and including them 'manually' in the replacement is easier.

Comment: question ...  Just tested with `blah_blah_blah($something)` and it replaced it ---  Is there a way to get it to look specifically for `mysql_fetch_array`?  There are other like queries that I don't want it to touch.

Comment: Changed in edit. Add the specific string you want to match before the first paren.

Comment: Great, I edited my OP as well to denote that I was slightly unclear -- Thanks for you great solution and explanation!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
find . -type f -name "*.php" -exec sed -i'' -e 's/mysql_fetch_array(\$foo)/\$foo->fetch_array\(\)/g' {} +
```

Use `\` to escape `$` character, and in new value for replacement, `parenthesis` must be escaped too.

So, you need to use `\` for `(` and `)`

Comment: I think 'variable_here' was a placeholder

Comment: yes '$variable_here' is a placeholder hence the term "reusable string" in the title

Comment: @EliHeady hmm, I think it's a specific name! If it be a placaholder, your answer is better than me

Comment: @Zak so please use `foo` or `bar` for placaholders in your questions :)